# ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server PHP

Tags: php, ldap

I  am trying to autheticate Ldap with the Windows Active directory using php ldap.
Below is the code:

```
$ldaphost = "abc.flyway.org";

$ldapport = 389;

$ds = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport)

or die("Could not connect to $ldaphost");

if ($ds)
{
    $username = "human";
    $upasswd = "cryoutloud";

    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ds, $username, $upasswd);

    if ($ldapbind)
    {print "Congratulations! $username is authenticated.";}
    else
    {print "Nice try, Better luck next time!";}
}
```

When I leave the username blank, I get the congratulations message, but when using the username, I get the error. Please assist

Answer (score 0):

On the line `$username = "human ";` is there supposed to be a space there after the word `human`? Looks like a typo to me. When you leave it blank it will just try to bind anonymously. Try removing the trailing space.

Comment: Removed the space and still get the same result

Comment: Then the problem is on the ldap server side, not in your code. Unless, you are using OpenLDAP 2.x, in which case it is not returning a connection it is returning a resource. Please read the return values section here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a so called "Distinguished Name" (DN) to bind to an LDAP-Server. If you omit that and leave the "BindDN"-Parameter blank you will get an anonymous login which might (or might not) work depending on the LDAP-Server you are talking to. ActiveDirectory after 2013 f.i. doesn't allow anonymous bind any more.

The DN can look somewhat like `uid=<username>,dc=users,o=example,c=com` or completely different but it is NEVER simply a username. So if you want to authenticate a user by it's username you will have to search for the DN of a user with that username using either a known User (you can get from your LDAP-Admin) or anonymous access.

I've created a gist to illustrate that at https://gist.github.com/heiglandreas/5689592 - Feel free to ping me if you've got more questions regarding LDAP.